# Return a std::stringstream - Compilation Fail

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, move-semantics

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream foo() {
  std::stringstream log;
  log << "Hello there\n";
  return log;
}
```

`GCC 4.9.2` gives me the following error (with `-std=c++11`):

```
[x86-64 gcc 4.9.2] error: use of deleted function
    'std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)'
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/cvcC3Y) an example.

Since the `std::stringstream` has [`move constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream), why the copy constructor is invoked, instead of the move constructor?

*Note*: from `GCC 5` the code compile correctly: [see here](https://godbolt.org/g/CWO0kh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take a look at the [GCC 5 changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) we can see:

> Full support for C++11, including the following new features:
>
> - std::deque and std::vector meet the allocator-aware container requirements;
> - **movable and swappable iostream classes;**
>
> ...

The change in bold is what's making your code compile on GCC 5 and fail to compile on 4.9, the move constructor simply wasn't implemented yet for `std::stringstream`.

Comment: I thought since the option `-std=c++11`, `GCC 4.9.2` fully supported the entire standard.